# Marshalling an XML file as a Spring bean

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

Can anyone give me a hint how could I marshall a bean from a static XML file (`main/resources/config.xml`) in Spring? I'd like to get Spring to do all the work for me, hopefully with some magic in the spring `applicationContext.xml` file.

For example, I have the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="config")
public class MyConfig
{
  private List<FooBar> foobars;

  //constructor, getter + setter
}

@XmlType(name="fooBar")
public class FooBar
{
  private String name;
  private Foo foo;
  private Bar bar;

  //constructor, getters + setters
}

@XmlType(name="foo")
public class Foo
{
  private String name;

  //constructor, getters + setters
}

@XmlType(name="bar")
public class Bar
{
  private String name;

  //constructor, getters + setters
}
```

And I want a bean loading with this XML;

```
<config>
  <fooBar>
    <name>foobar1</name>
    <foo>
      <name>foo1</name>
    </foo>
    <bar>
      <name>bar1</name>
    </bar>
  </fooBar>
  <fooBar>
    <name>foobar2</name>
    <foo>
      <name>foo2</name>
    </foo>
    <bar>
      <name>bar2</name>
    </bar>
  </fooBar>
</config>
```

I could just write a constructor and pass in the XML file as a resource, but I have the feeling that Spring has already solved the problem for me, I just can't find out how.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Spring does not include any non-spring configuration related xml processing.  This may be the solution you want though: [castor](http://www.castor.org/).  This is not the only tool like this.  It is; however, the only one that I can think of atm.

Comment: If you don't need the Java-to-SQL bindings castor provides, XStream (http://xstream.codehaus.org/) provides functionality for Java<->XML